# Import error Twisted on windows

Tags: python, twisted

While trying to run a simple twisted code, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 322, in RunScript
debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
_GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
 File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 655, in run
exec cmd in globals, locals
File "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\my.py", line 1, in <module>
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet.protocol
```

I installed twisted using the .exe installer successfully.

Comment: are you installed to the right place? Possible cause is you have different python versions, e.g. 2.5, 2.7, you are invoking 2.5 but it is installed to a different verion of python.

Comment: oh yes,i have installed twisted in python27..
so how do i make it run on python 2.7??

Comment: Add the `C:\Python27` folder to your `PATH` and remove Python25 from it (or uninstall python 2.5). You can set the path from My Computer -> (right click) Properties -> Advanced system settings -> environment variables. You also may need to reinstall twisted.

Comment: Thanx a lot...everything fine now.....

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed right version of twisted. For example, if you are using python 2.7, twisted installer should like: Twisted-13.0.0.win32-py2.7.msi

Installer will configure Environment PATH, if not u must configure then restart Windows.